# ng-repeat horizontal images

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a list of images horizontal. They keep displaying vertical. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in product.images">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li>
            <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{i.image}}"> </img>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: that's weird. the css looks like it will make them horizontal. can you create a jsfiddle to showcase it? else it looks good to me.

Comment: Shouldn't your `ng-repeat` be _inside_ the `ul`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the 'ng-repeat' in the li tag (not the div), otherwise you are repeating the entire div, which is not inline.  Here's a link to a CodePen with this code http://codepen.io/jwncoexists/pen/XbdOVY

```
<body ng-app="ImageDemo">
  <div ng-controller="Demo.controller">
    <div>
      <ul id="navlist">
        <li ng-repeat="i in product.images">
          <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{i.image}}"> 
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

calthoff, if you remove the ul, li and float the images..then how about this for simplicity's sake:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in product.images">
     <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{i.image}}">
</div>


img
{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="i in product.images">
<ul id="navlist">
    <li>
        <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{i.image}}" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{i.image}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

< img > tags are self-closing, your code should work like this.

Comment: Oh right good call on the img tag. It is horizontal that way but not doing quite what I want because I don't know how many images there are going to be in advance, so I don't want to make <li> tags in advance. Is there anyway to get the images horizontal with just one set of <li> tags us ng-repeat?

Comment: yes, between jennifers answer and mine you should have it